# Holder.js and Bootstrap cards - Can't get img data-src to display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, holder.js

Im a newbie and I can't get my image to display when using holder.js and bootstrap cards. I ran across holder.js as the first solution to creating bootstrap cards so that's what I'm trying to use. If there is a better solution I'm all ears.

```
<div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="http://seeklogo.com/images/P/Polaris-logo-F1A7D948C6-seeklogo.com.gif" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Here is my header where I've called in holder.js

```
<head>
<title>James Scaggs Portfolio - JamesScaggs.com</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/holder-master/holder.js"></script>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found the right answer here: [Can't figure out how to use Bootstrap thumbnail component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017532/cant-figure-out-how-to-use-bootstrap-thumbnail-component)

I removed data-src and used just src instead and it works.

Can anyone explain when someone would need/want to use holder.js? I'm not understanding the purpose of using data-src.